# How to get projectile to move in the direction the player is facing

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, unityscript, projectile

This is the code for my player's movement:

```
var animator : Animator;

function Start () {
    animator = GetComponent("Animator");
}


var moveUp : KeyCode;
var moveDown : KeyCode;
var moveLeft : KeyCode;
var moveRight : KeyCode;
var jumpheight : int = 2;
var speed : int = 2;
var isGrounded : int = 0;

// Checks if player is in air or ground

var Jumptest : int = 0;

// Checks if player has jumped

function Update () {

    animator.SetInteger("Direction", 4);

    if (Input.GetKey(moveUp) && isGrounded == 0)
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.y = jumpheight;
        isGrounded = 1;
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 2);
    }


    else if (Input.GetKey(moveLeft))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 3);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(moveRight))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 1);
    }

}
```

and this is the code for the projectiles movement:

```
#pragma strict

var speed  = 8.0;
var time = 0.0;


function Start () {

}

var moveRight : KeyCode;
var moveLeft : KeyCode;

function Update () {
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    if(time > 3){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
}
```

At the moment, the projectiles shoot to the right. I want to be able to shoot them in the direction the player is facing.

I tried if key down a and if key down d but then the projectiles stop when the player is not moving and move relative to the player (if I shoot one going left, then move my player to the right, the projectile reverses direction).

Anybody know?

Comment: just change `Vector3.right` to `Vector3.forward`. Supposing you `Instantiate`d the projectile with the player's rotation.

Answer (score 0):

When checking for player movement , whether the left/right key is down, you create a simple integer which keeps track of direction

```
...
var isRight: int=1 ;//assuming player starts with facing in the right direction
...
```

and then, when checking for key press set the value of this variable appropriately

```
...
else if (Input.GetKey(moveLeft)&&!Input.GetKey(moveRight))
{
    isRight = -1;
    ...
}
else if (Input.GetKey(moveRight)&&!Input.GetKey(moveLeft))
{
    isRight = 1;  
    ...
}
```

Finally when setting translation for the projectile simply multiply the speed with this new variable

```
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * isRight * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
```